# NetSuite PHP toolkit integration with CakePHP framework

Tags: netsuite

I have downloaded the latest php toolkit version from NetSuite. I had made my config settings and the sample files run perfectly in my localhost. However, when i try to integrate with cake php i always get host connection error.I tried integrating the php toolkit through my vendor using cakephp.So is there any possible method to integrate the php toolkit with cake php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Host connection error indicates that NSconfig.php file is not being included properly. Check the path you are using to include this file.

Although not much relevant but You may get basic idea from this post http://dreamxtream.wordpress.com/2013/08/05/integrating-netsuite-php-toolkit-in-yii/